# BUILD FAILED when I want to get SHA1 ran gradlew signingReport on my android studio

Tags: android, flutter, sha1

I want to get SHA 1 and ran ../gradlew signingReport and got following error:
PS D:\programing\FONTANATRAVELWITHACCOUNTDELETE\apps\rider-app\android\app> ../gradlew signingreport

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'D:\programing\FONTANATRAVELWITHACCOUNTDELETE\apps\rider- 
app\android\settings.gradle' line: 6

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.
> assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
         |                   |
         |                   false
         D:\programing\FONTANATRAVELWITHACCOUNTDELETE\apps\rider- 
app\android\local.properties

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 693ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Open ***settings.gradle*** file in the Android folder and make sure it looks something like this:

```
include ':app'

def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()

assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

Comment: Thanks for your replying,but  I checked and make sure that I have these code